# Conflict in merging

Tags: angular, git, typescript

I have some troubles in my project angular. Who can help me ?

> ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(5,1): error TS1185: Merge conflict marker encountered.

Comment: Hmm.. Have you tried resolving the merge conflict

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: @wentjun @mbojko Looks like an error which is being thrown by the `TypeScript` compiler.

Comment: @DavidR Yes, the reason why the TS compiler is throwing that error, is because when there are markers being inserted to the code to denote the presence of merge conflicts.. Such markers cannot be properly compiled/transpiled

Comment: Still, I really can't imagine an answer different than "resolve the merge conflict".

Comment: Exactly! All will be fine once the merge conflict is resolved..

Comment: @wentjun Got it!.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You possibly selected 'add routing' = yes when you first created your app in the Angular CLI, so the file app-routing.module already exists in the src/app folder.

Answer (score 2):

Just go through path that is `src/app/app-routing.module.ts` and delete this `app-routing.module.ts` file and then again install it using `ng g module app-routing --flat --module=app`.

Answer (score 0):

Open `src/app/app-routing.module.ts` file in your editor and look through it.
On line 5 there probably is something like `<<<<<<< HEAD...`
Which marks where git could not automatically merge 2 branches and you need to manually edit this file and tell what does it have to look like exactly now.

In other words, remove all non-typescript code.